# Responsive menu not showing Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).on is not a function in wordpress website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am developing a website on `wordpress` and it works perfectly fine in its desktop version but when we open it in mobile, its responsive menu gets switched but does not show anything while clicking on that.
When we go to developers console in google chrome, it shows the following error.

> Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).on is not a function.

When I checked it in the coding, it shows the following code.

```
jQuery('#navmenu').prepend('<div id="menu-icon">Menu</div>');
jQuery("#menu-icon").on("click", function(){
    jQuery("#navmenu .menu").slideToggle();
    jQuery(this).toggleClass("menu_active");
});
```

Page URL: http://www.marksystest.in/ibt

Please help me out.

Comment: It's impossible to tell from the code in your question (questions should include a complete test case so they don't depend on external URLs!) but you are loading jQuery twice. Near the end of the document you have `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` which overwrites jQuery with an ancient version that doesn't support `on`.

Comment: So what should I do? Should I remove the another jquery <script> tag??

Comment: Yes, remove the 1.3 version of jquery, that's a lot of years old.

Comment: This is a wordpress website and I am using Isis theme in it. I am using Wowslider plugin for slider. I am not too sure from where I need to remove it. Can you elaborate it a little bit more @Marcos Perez Gude

Comment: No, can you elaborate a little bit your code with your problem? I don't know what's your code or in where file is included. Search in all your project the string `1.3/jquery.min.js` and see where is and remove it

Comment: My apologies for being a beginner and not understanding what you are asking to do but a little bit more help on how to do it will be appreciated.

Comment: That's no related with the experience. You could be a begginner but you can ask a quality question with a working example. You can read this mandatory topics: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask | https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ Otherwiser you will be notice a lot of questions removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your web page jquery is getting added twice once in the top part (v11) of the code and another at the bottom (v.1.3) so go to footer.php and search for v.1.3 jquery and remove that line.

Comment: If I will remove v1.3, will it create any issues for the code which is using the version 1.3??

Answer (score 1):

You Use `jquery.min.js` online OR offline

**FOR ONLINE**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**FOR OFFLINE**

Download and set in `<script>` tag
[Click here](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js)

Comment: Thank You for your efforts. I have removed the <script> from footer containing jquery 1.3 version. Now it is working completely fine....